# .NET image not displaying in PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

.NET strikes again...

At some random point it stopped showing the images in 2 of my picture boxes. Any picture box created from that point on has the same problem. The designer files (which I'm starting to think would save a lot of time if I created them myself, in stead of having Visual Studio generate them and then mess them up) show nothing that looks strange to me. The picture boxes in question are pbxVolume1 and pbxVolume2. Other picture boxes created before those 2 like pbxPitch1 work fine.

Please assist.

The whole solution can be found at http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~robinj/quantum-mix/trunk/files/2

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried recreating the PictureBoxes or the image resources? I would first try deleting the image from your resources and re-adding it. If you can't find a problem in the designer code, look at your resources.

Comment: I have already tried that. I have even tried restoring my machine to a point before Visual Studio was installed, installing it again, creating a new project, copying code over piece by piece, and then rebuilding the project. The same problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

I've got your solution and tried it myself. Same problem here: image is loaded in designer and not when running. **But** if I open Resources.resx and just save it without touching anything, when I run project, everything is fine.

So, it seems that your VS is broken. Do you have installed [service pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691) and related updates?

Comment: I just installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. No service packs as far as I can tell.

Comment: Look in Help/About to see if you already have SP. Documentation for SP1 link above says: "Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1) will upgrade **all editions** and languages of Visual Studio 2010 you have already installed."

Comment: In other words, you should install SP :)

Comment: Do you really think that will fix anything?

Comment: I think your VS resources designer breaks .resx file. Updating VS is worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have found your solution by now. But for reference, I would still like to mention the following alternative for future problems regarding the same issue.

Try creating a .dll of your resource file and include it in your project by "Add Reference". This will make sure your images are always available and you will not have Resource.resx problem as above. Have the original resource file as part of a different solution. Include images you require and create the .dll file. Include this .dll file in your main solution. 
Any changes to the resource file should be made in a separate solution and the .dll re-generated to update the change. You only have to include the updated .dll in your main solution.